# Redshift COPY command How to handle special character from S3

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

Getting error , when we load some special in the line from s3 bucket. How to handle this issue.

```
**해당 **data** 사용 하지 않을 가능성이 있어 **check**으로 이동시키기**
```

Comment: Translation: `**There is a possibility that the **data** will not be used, so move it to **check****`

Comment: Please edit your question to show the commands you ran when you received this error.